# Workflow rules not working on Merge Request in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I am trying to run the below script as gitlab-ci.yml but somehow I am not able to trigger the CICD pipeline with a merge request.

Steps I am following:

1. Create a branch from feature/new and name it as feature/abc
2. Make test changes to feature/abc
3. Create Merge request with target branch as feature/new.

```yaml
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - deployment
  - testing

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "feature/new"'

deployment-dev: # This job runs in the deploy stage.
  stage: deployment
     
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - echo hello

    
  environment:
    name: main/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  when: on_success
testing-dev:   # This job also runs in the test stage.
  stage: testing  
      
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - echo testing in progress
```

Comment: It's correctly working on my side testing your `gitlab-ci.yml`. I use Gitlab `13.12.8-ee`

Comment: I would also want to know how we can implement MR queuing. If there are multiple MRs (MR1, MR2, MR3), then the pipeline should run for MR1 and the other two should wait for the first to complete. I dont see this happening natively in gitlab.

Comment: That's not the purpose of your question but about that, check https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/resource_groups/